# Can we extend existing classes with custom functions? (No inheritance)

Tags: c++, class, methods

I'm looking for a way to extend a C++ class with a custom member method. Just like C# does that with Linq extensions:

```
public static class Factory
{
    public static int getIndex(this List<int> source, int value)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (int item in source)
        {
            if (item == value)
                return index;
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This C# Code would add a method to every Instance of a List. So you can write:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(26);
myList.Add(42);
myList.Add(37);
myList.Add(3);
int index = myList.getIndex(42);
```

Is that somehow possible in C++ aswell? How can I properly add such a method to a `std::vector<T>` **without subclassing** it?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find anything answering my question without using inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is solely to extend std c++ container classes you should think in terms of algorithms and not member methods.

Consider this code. **No error checking for brevity**

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

// returns the second element
template< typename T>
int getSecond(T begin)
{
  begin++;
  return *begin;
}


int main()
{

  std::vector<int> intlist;
  intlist.push_back(1);
  intlist.push_back(2);
  intlist.push_back(3);

  std::set<int> intset;
  intset.insert(1);
  intset.insert(3);
  intset.insert(2);

  std::cout << "Second in vector " << getSecond(intlist.begin()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Second in set " << getSecond(intset.begin()) << std::endl;

}
```

Now one could have hypothetically modelled getSecond as a member of std::vector but modeling it as a stand alone function that takes an iterator is very powerful as the same function could be used with sets deques etc.

If you have **N** containers and **M** algorithms as members functions you would have **N * M** functions but as stand alone algorithm functions there would be considerably less code

Comment: Why post-increment? You don't need the side-effect.

Comment: @JorenHeit That's just style. It has no effect on performance in most practical cases.

Comment: Yeah I know that this is possible with a stand-alone function and Templates. But I only use `std::vector` in my program so far and it would improve the readability a lot if I could extend this class with a member function of mine.

Comment: In which case why not do **class myvector : public std::vector** and use myvector everywhere

Comment: @parapurarajkumar I heard its bad behaviour to inherit std classes

Comment: @Vinzenz Well yes, it is because it is good behavior to use algorithms instead. Anyway extending is inheriting. It's just a weird work-around that saves you the "trouble" of making it explicit to other that your code it totally not re-usable because you grafted so other functionality on a standard and well defined interface. C++ doesn't provide this features because "it is bad behaviour" too.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe You can never tell when dealing with templates, `T` might be anything. I therefore consider it *bad* style.

Comment: @JorenHeit: You can apply `++` to any iterator type. You can't necessarily write `return *(begin+1);` (assuming that's what you think the code should do instead), since that's only supported by random-access iterators. So `++` is the better style.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm not objecting to the use of `++`. I'm objecting to the use of post-increment rather than pre-increment.